# Performance for Creating multiple pyspark data frames and merging them together

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a requirement where I read a json in dataframe. Flatten it because it has 3 arrays. Create 3 different data frames for 3 different arrays and finally merge them together after some transformations. I want to check counts for each data frames before writing the final merged one. What can be some performance enhancement tips here?

Schema of Json looks like:

```
-id (string)
-as_of_date (string)
-past_features (array)
  -height (string)
  -width (string)
  -screensize (string)
  -smartdevice (boolean)
  -version(string)
-current_features (array)
  -height (string)
  -width (string)
  -screensize (string)
  -smartdevice (boolean)
  -version(string)
-future_features (array)
  -height (string)
  -width (string)
  -screensize (string)
  -smartdevice (boolean)
  -version(string)
```

- There are 3  Array fields and the length of array fields(number of
  records)can vary for a json record.
- Also it can vary among other json records(means can be blank for
  some.)
- I am extracting 3 different dataframes from this Json data:
- extracting (id| as_of_date and array columns) for individual array
  columns in separate dataframes, exploding them and then selecting
  fields inside them as columns.

df1=id| as_of_date|feature|height|width|screensize|smartdevice|version|features

features column here will have value -"past_feature" for all records

df2=id| as_of_date|feature|height|width|screensize|smartdevice|version|features

features column here will have value -"current_feature" for all records

df3=id| as_of_date|feature|height|width|screensize|smartdevice|version|features

features column here will have value -"future_feature" for all records

I want to then append all these together dfs and save that flattened data in CSV.
I want to take count of individual dataframes & the combined one and then write to CSV.

How can i improve performance if Json would contain around 600k records and each array inside a single record can have 14 items each in array so total flattened data(rows) can be around (600k*42 records)?

Comment: Please share some code to understand more about the use case

Comment: edited my query with more details on the problem statement.

Comment: Could you please also add some code of what you have tried so far? so we can check what can be improved